# trying to increment simon game level in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javaScript and trying to create a simon game in jS and want to increase level everytime nextSequence() is called

```js
var started = false; //toggler
var level = 0;
$(document).on("keydown", function() {
  if (!started) {
    $("h1").text("Level 0")
    nextSequence()

    started = true;
  }
})


function nextSequence() {
  var randomNumber = Math.random() * 4;
  randomNumber = Math.floor(randomNumber);
  var randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber] //any one color
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor);

  $("#" + randomChosenColor).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100); // animate
  level = level + 1
  console.log(level)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looks like we're missing a couple things from the snippet but what exactly isn't working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have all of the necessary variables set (buttonColors). The variable level should be increased by one every key down, if you want to display the score through the h1 you would need to incorporate the 'score' variable into the text

so change `$("h1").text("Level 0")` to `$("h1").text("Level " + level)`